# I/O errors when trying to copy data off a drive

Tags: hard-drive

I'm trying to copy data off of an old SATA drive that ran Ubuntu but it erroring out saying `Input/Output Error`.

What would cause that error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I/O error means that the Hard Drive can't read a certain location. It can be caused by a bad sector.

You can use ddrescue.

> ddrescue is a data recovery tool. It copies data from one file or
>   block device (hard disc, cdrom, etc) to another, trying hard to rescue
>   data in case of read errors.<sup>1</sup>

You can download the latest release [Here](http://mirror.veriportal.com/gnu/ddrescue/), or through the Ubuntu Software Center

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ddrescue](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddrescue/ddrescue.html)</sup>